# How to abstract duplicate JSX to a Higher Order Component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components

I'm trying to learn how to write Higher Order Components and I have two components that are very similar in code. Far as I know duplicate code is a good candidate for an HOC. I can't seem to wrap my head around how to write an HOC for when it pertains to additional JSX injected into a component.

To give a small example let's say I have these two components:

```js
const MySection = (props) => (
  <div passedProp={props.passed} >
    <Row>
      <FirstName />
    </Row>

    <Row>
      <LastName />
    </Row>
  </div>
);


const MySectionWithConfirmation = (props) => (
  <div passedProp={props.passed} >
    <Row>
      <FirstName />
      <ConfirmFirstName />
    </Row>

    <Row>
      <LastName />
      <ConfirmLastName />
    </Row>
  </div>
);
```

Is the above something that can be made an HOC? How would something like that be rewritten?

Answer (score 4):

You could add a prop for `confirm` and have a single reusable component, no HOC needed. Something like:

```js
const MySectionWithOptionalConfirmation = (props) => (
    <div passedProp={props.passed} >
      <Row>
        <FirstName />
        {props.confirm && <ConfirmFirstName />}
      </Row>

      <Row>
        <LastName />
        {props.confirm && <ConfirmLastName />}
      </Row>
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: Useful, thanks. Was hoping for composition over configuration.